# React works in production but white screen in build

Tags: reactjs, bundle, create-react-app

I have a react app implemented with `create-react-app`. When I view the site locally using `npm run start`, it works fine. But when I build it using `npm run build` and view the built site, it's just a blank white screen with the following errors.[image]

When I go into the compiled `build/index.html` and look at the links, they're all missing `.` before them, such as `<link href="/static/css/main.60d8d896.chunk.css"`. and   Adding `.` before the `/` fixes many of the errors and makes the site no longer a blank white screen, but even after doing that to all of the links I can find many of the SVG icons on my site are completely missing and the console logs these errors. [image]

It seems that for some reason the build is just messing up all of the links, which has never happened before and is unexpected considering the production version works fine.

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/michaelmoreno/3d2f3111037ee75e7b0c433a93e1c318) of the compiled `build/index.html`, and here's the [source code](https://github.com/michaelmoreno/portfolio) to the entire react app.

Comment: Yes, just nginx on a VPS.

Comment: Does it work when you serve on your local machine using a static server like [serve](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#static-server)?

Comment: I just tried that, and yes it works. That means the problem must be with my remote nginx server, but when I do sudo systemctl status nginx it shows it's actively running..

Comment: And when I stop the nginx server, the site doesn't load at all, meaning the white screen IS being served by nginx.

Comment: I just deleted all of the build files in my remote nginx and resent it with `scp` and it is working now, so I guess I just messed that part up. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I just wasn't serving the files correctly on my remote nginx server. I must have sent the files using `scp` incorrectly, because when I deleted all of the files and re-scp'd it, it worked properly.